# What is the difference between Class and Class<?>?

Tags: java, reflection

If there is any, what's the difference if I use `Class` or `Class<?>` as return type for example? Are there any cases where I should pay attention to use one or the other?

Comment: use `Class<?>`, `Class` is a [rawtype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `Class` is a rawtype and **you should avoid using such**.
2. `Class<?>` represents a parametrized by an *unknown* type `Class`.

At runtime, there's no difference between `Class` and `Class<?>`, at all. First, they are both converted to a generic `Class<Object>` and finally the type is erased (because of the [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)).

Comment: Why would I want to avoid rawtypes, if these two are converted to the same at runtime?

Comment: Because raw types are compilation-error prone. If you use Generics, the compiler checks if the operations you do with the types are correct and rejects compiling if a possible `ClassCastException` could occur at Runtime. Using raw types only, the compiler shows a warning only, saying "I hope you know what you do".

Answer (score 0):

This is a subset of the more general generics question about the difference between Anything and Anything<?>.

There is a reasonably clear description of it in the main java tutorials on generics:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html